# Convert PHP http post request to Livecode

Tags: php, http, http-post, livecode

I am new to Livecode and I have tried couple of things to convert this php http post request code to Livecode but not working. Will need it either with cURL or without cURL.

```
    $receive_momo_request = array(
         'CustomerName' => 'Customer Name',
      'CustomerMsisdn'=> '054XXXX',
      'CustomerEmail'=> 'customer@gmail.com',
      'Channel'=> 'mtn-gh',
      'Amount'=> 0.8,
      'PrimaryCallbackUrl'=> 'http://requestb.in/1minotz1',
      'Description'=> 'T Shirt',

);

//API Keys

$clientId = 'xxxxxxx';
$clientSecret = 'xxxxxxx';
$basic_auth_key =  'Basic ' . base64_encode($clientId . ':' . $clientSecret);
$request_url = 'https://api.hubtel.com/v1/merchantaccount/merchants/HMXXXXXXX/receive/mobilemoney';
$receive_momo_request = json_encode($receive_momo_request);

$ch =  curl_init($request_url);  
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );  
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $receive_momo_request);  
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );  
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: '.$basic_auth_key,
            'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
          ));

$result = curl_exec($ch); 
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($err){
    echo $err;
}else{
    echo $result;
}
```

This is what I have done so far may be am missing something.

```
on mouseUp
   global gFirstName, gLastName
   put gFirstName & " " & gLastName into lFullName
   put lFullName into tArray[ "CustomerName"]
   put "gPhoneNumber" into tArray["CustomerMsisdn"]
   put "gEmail"  into tArray["CustomerEmail"]
   put "airtel-gh" into tArray["Channel"]
   put "0.01" into tArray["Amount"]
   put "http://requestb.in/1minotz1" into tArray["PrimaryCallbackUrl"]
   put "FBMC Mobile" into tArray["Description"]
   put true into tArray ["FeesOnCustomer"]

   put ArrayToJSON(tArray) into receive_momo_request

   put "ABCD" into clientId
   put "1234" into clientSecret
   set the httpHeaders to "Content-type: application/json" && "Authorization: Basic " && base64Encode("clientId:clientSecret") && "Cache-Control: no-cache"
   post receive_momo_request to url "https://api.hubtel.com/v1/merchantaccount/merchants/HMXXXXXXX/receive/mobilemoney"

end mouseUp
```

Comment: Can you post code of what you have tried?

Comment: I have posted what i have tried so far

Comment: It can be helpful to post any errors or - what you observed that it didn't work. Are there errors? How do you know it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your LiveCode code looks good on first glance. I would try two things:

First, URLencode the data you are posting before you post it.

```
put ArrayToJSON(tArray) into receive_momo_request
put urlEncode(receive_momo_request) into receive_momo_request
```

Second, after the `post` command, check the `it`variable to see what data was returned by the web server. You can also check `the result` to see if an error occurred.

```
post receive_momo_request to url "https://api.hubtel.com/v1/merchantaccount/merchants/HMXXXXXXX/receive/mobilemoney"
put it into tServerFeedback
answer the result
```

This should at least tell you what is happening after you issue the `post` command.

Comment: The responds from the server : `{"ResponseCode":"4101","Message":"Permission denied"}`
`put  "Accept: application/json" &&"Authorization: Basic" && base64Encode("clientId:clientSecret") && "Cache-Control: no-cache" &&"Content-type: application/json" into tHeader
   
 set the httpHeaders to tHeader`
I believe the issue might by the header but not sure what is wrong but the authentication keys are all correct not sure why the server is denying access.